# Can I use 2 microphones with pi? & receive those two input-signals respectively?

Tags: raspbian, audio, input-device

Can I use 2 microphones with pi? & receive those two input-signals respectively?I want to receive two sound signals respectively in raspberry pi. In this case, just plug in two usb-microphones and receive each signal? Please, give me some advice..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You can either use a single USB audio device with stereo inputs (I use an old Griffin [iMic](http://griffintechnology.com/imic)) or use two USB mono inputs. I prefer the former — not just because I already have the hardware to do it — as it means fewer devices to support, and fewer potential sync errors between the audio streams.

For instance, I've used a Raspberry Pi, the iMic, and a binaural microphone set
clamped to a 30 cm steel rule to demonstrate range finding by calculating the delay between the left and right channel signal.

Comment: Are there any problems in ensuring the level is equal between the channels?  I was thinking that if one channel was more sensitive than the other it would trigger at a lower threshold and give misleading timings.

Comment: Yes, there would be, but I was using very percussive noises with short attack times, so the timing error was small.